# Recognize 'a' in a sentence and indicate as 1 @sys.number in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I would like `Dialogflow` to detect `a` in a sentence and give it a `number = 1`.

Example: I would like to have **a** chicken rice.

`Dialogflow` should detect as:

```
'a' = @sys.number, Resolved value : one or 1

"chicken rice" = @delivery-product, resolved value : chicken rice
```

I already have an entity to detect the product, a intent to detect single order or multiple order,

i.e. "I want 2 chicken rice and 2 coffee" . 
this would return me both numbers and products.

However I just can't get `Dialogflow` to detect:
I want **a** coffee
I want 2 chicken rice and **a** coffee.

Anyone have any recommendation to tackle this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried creating a seperate entity for recognizing 'a' and mapping it to 1 by using synonyms? If you have an entity with value 1 and 'a' as a synonym. I think it could recognize it.

Comment: @Jordi Hi thanks for the suggestion, but this still did not solve my issue. I would need to extract the value and use in fulfillment. However I have solve the issue by creating a developer enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new custom entity with the synonym of **"1"** as **"a**" and then add that custom entity in a new custom entity with "**@sys.number**". Do not add synonyms for this entity. Use the second custom entity in your intent training phrases. [image: custom-entity] [image: custom-number] [image: intent]

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I am currently using this method and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Great. It’s my pleasure to help you.